# Mockolate - Calling the same method on a mock with the same arguments but return different results

Tags: actionscript-3, mocking, tdd, flexunit4, mockolate

I'am using Mockolate and flex unit 4 to write mocks for my tests in AS3. I want to call the same method on a mock with the same arguments multiple 
times and return a different result each time. A basic example is:

```
            [Rule] 
            public var mocks:MockolateRule = new MockolateRule(); 

            [Mock(type="strict")] 
            public var list:IList; 

            [Test] 
            public function test():void{ 

                    var seq:Sequence = sequence(); 
                    expecting(function ():void { 
                            expect(list.getItemAt(0)).returns("Item1").thrice().inSequence(seq); 
                            expect(list.getItemAt(0)).returns("Item2").inSequence(seq); 
                            expect(list.getItemAt(0)).returns("Item3").inSequence(seq); 
                    }); 

                    trace(list.getItemAt(0)); 
                    trace(list.getItemAt(0)); 
                    trace(list.getItemAt(0)); 

                    verify(list); 
            }
```

This results in:

```
Item1 
Item2 
Item2
```

And and error:

```
1 unmet Exception
```

What I want is

```
Item1 
Item2 
Item2
```

and no exceptions, i.e. test passes.

I've tried a few alternatives such as:

```
                    expecting(function ():void { 
                            expect(list.getItemAt(0)).returns("Item1").inSequence(seq); 
                            expect(list.getItemAt(0)).returns("Item2").inSequence(seq); 
                            expect(list.getItemAt(0)).returns("Item3").inSequence(seq); 
                    });
```

and others to no avail. Surely I'm missing something simple here. This 
seems like something that should be easy.

Thanks guys,

Theo.

Comment: I'm not sure: do you want to assert if calling `list.getItemAt(0)` first time returns "item1", second time returns "item2" and third time returns "item3"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bugged the hell out of me, until I found out it is really very simple: Just use all the expected return values as parameters to the first `returns()` statement.

```
 expect(list.getItemAt(0)).returns("Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4").inSequence(seq);
```

The mock will return the last of these parameters for each subsequent call.